# Supplying Float Arguments through Command Prompt C Language

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I'm having difficulty using the command prompt to take variables (Written in the command prompt) and use them in the program. The idea is that i compile the program using:

gcc main.c

and execute it by running the a.exe that is created followed by the arguments.

As follows:

C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\resistance>gcc main.c

C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\resistance>a.exe 0.0005 1.5 160

48.000000 49.000000 49.000000 Not enough arguments supplied

The final row is the value's I receive back from the code which are not correct as seen by the arguments I have supplied.

As well as the fact that the code is terminated by the "Not enough arguments supplied" if statement. This again is confusing since *argv[] begins at 0 *argv[0] which should be equal to "a.exe" and therefore following arguments should = *argv[1]... ect

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

float areaOfcircle(float radius_circle)
{
    float area_circle;
    area_circle = M_PI * radius_circle * radius_circle;

    return area_circle;
}
void resitance_current(float length, float area_circle, float voltage, float* resistance, float* current)
{
    float resistivity;
    resistivity = 1.782*pow(10, -8);
    *resistance = ((resistivity*length) / area_circle);
    *current = (voltage / *resistance);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    float radius, voltage, length, current, resistance;
    float length_u, length_l;
    voltage = *argv[1];
    length = *argv[2];
    radius = *argv[3];
    printf("%f %f %f", voltage, length, radius);
    //char response, yes;
    // take radius as input
    //printf("Enter the radius of wire : ");
    //scanf("%f", &radius);
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Not enough arguments supplied");
    }
    else
    {
        if (radius < 0)
        {
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            //printf("Enter the Voltage of circuit : ");
            //scanf("%f", &voltage);
            if (voltage < 0)
            {
                exit(1);
            }
            else
            {
                //printf("Enter the Length of Wire : ");
                //scanf("%f", &length);
                if (length < 0)
                {
                    exit(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    resitance_current(length, areaOfcircle(radius), voltage, &resistance, &current);
                    printf("Resistance = %f , Current = %f\n", resistance, current);
                    printf("\nEnter the Upper Length of Wire : ");
                    scanf("%f", &length_u);
                    printf("\nEnter the Lower Length of Wire : ");
                    scanf("%f", &length_l);
                    if ((length_l < 0) || (length_l >= length_u))
                    {
                        exit(1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for(length_l = length_l; length_l<=length_u; length_l++)
                        {
                            length = (length_l + 1);
                            resitance_current(length, areaOfcircle(radius), voltage, &resistance, &current);
                            printf("\nLength = %0.3f Resistance = %0.3f , Current = %0.3f", length, resistance, current);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

On lines 23-25 I try and assign variable names the arguments provided. to make reading them through the code easier.

The main issue I'm trying to find help with is how to get (Integer/Float numbers read/entered from the command line following the program.exe name and used correctly in the code.

*The code was pre-written with this been the final step so if I've missed anything in the code please help with that as well, Thanks in advance. Hope you can help :)

Comment: Are you expecting a voltage of 0.0005 (V?) a length of 1.5 (m?) and a radius of 160 (m??)?

Comment: yes, i am. Bob_

Comment: Isn't it the other way around (160 V and a radius of 0.0005m or maybe 1.5 V and a length of 160m)? Maybe I'm overthinking or using the wrong units, but still, that doesn't really seem a *wire*...

Comment: OT: regarding: `gcc main.c`  that is a terrible way to compile/ link a program.  Suggest: `gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 main.c -o main.o`  and when it compiles with no errors nor warnings, then `gcc main.o -o main`

Comment: OT:  regarding: `printf("Not enough arguments supplied");`  This tells the user (almost) nothing other than they made an error.  Much better to use: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s  voltage length radius\n", argv[0] );` as that outputs to `stderr` (as it should) and tells the user what should have been on the command line,

Comment: regarding: `if (argc != 3)`  the parameter `argc` includes the `argv[0]` which is the name of the executable. Therefore the value to check against is 4, not 3

Comment: Check the parameter `argc` before accessing the actual arguments otherwise the code will cause a seg fault event when it tries to access beyond the actual arguments

Comment: regarding: `voltage = *argv[1];
    length = *argv[2];
    radius = *argv[3];`  the actual arguments will always be char arrays,  The contents of those arrays need to be converted to float values.  perhaps via: `sscanf(  argv[1], "%f", &voltage );
    sscanf( argv[2], "%f", &length );
    sscanf( argv[3], "%f", &radius );`  of course, the code should be checking the returned value to assure the operation was successful, similar to: `if( sscanf( argv[3], "%f", &radius ) != 1 ) { fprintf( stderr, "sscanf for radius failed\n" ); }`

Comment: this is the syntax for `pow()` "double pow(double x, double y);" but all the code is using `float`, not `double`  so should use the function: `float powf(float x, float y);`  and for: `pow(10, -8);` both parameters are 'int', not `double`  after correcting for using the correct function, the statement should be:  `resistivity = 1.782f*powf(10.0f, -8.0f);`   I.E. a `float` literal contains a decimal point and a trailing 'f'

Comment: regarding: `for(length_l = length_l; length_l<=length_u; length_l++)` the compiler will output a warning message about the first parameter.  Suggest: `for( ; length_l <= length_u; length_l++ )`

Comment: regarding: `length = (length_l + 1);`  the compiler will output a warning about this statement.  Suggest: `length = (length_l + 1.0f);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try printing out the value of `argc` and all of the `argv` strings to see what they are. You might be in for a surprise. Add the following function to your code:

```
void dumpargs(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
  int i;

  printf("argc = %d\n", argc);

  for(i = 0 ; i < argc ; ++i)
    printf("argv[%d] = '%s'\n", i, argv[i]));
  }
```

then add the following as the first line after the variable declarations in `main`:

```
dumpargs(argc, argv);
```

Answer (score 2):

warning the pathname of the program is the first argument, so *argc* must be compared to 4 in your case, this is why you have that behavior

an other remark : you need to check argc **before** to access to argv

Answer (score 2):

What does this do?

```
  voltage = *argv[1];
    length = *argv[2];
    radius = *argv[3]
```

You are trying to take a string value and assign it to a float.  That will not work.  You need convert the string using something like the atof() function (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atof.htm).

```
ex;   voltage = atof(argv[1])
```

Also compile with full warnings.